# Changing labels from external CSV in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, csv, topojson

I got my hands on a TopoJSON map that unfortunately uses a mix of names for the polygons, sometimes the official name, sometimes not (English). I do, however, have the ISO3 code, which is great.

I also do have a dataset with the official names I would like to use in this TopoJSON file. Is it possible to replace a specific attribute by matching it with a CSV?

Comment: You need a common key/ID, then this is perfectly possible, e.g. using a `join` in the layer properties.

Comment: I do have a common ID, I can use either ISO 2-letter code or 3-letter code, which exist in both the topojson file and the CSV. I tried to add new field but when I go to Attribute table, this option is greyed out for me

Comment: To which layer are you trying to add a new field. Why are you trying to do so?

Comment: I am trying to replace a property in the TopoJSON file. The names of the countries are not consistent. I want to use this TopoJSON file as a map in my BI tool that will match my data by the country name. On the database side I have a dataset that has all countries' names in standardised, official convention. Both data sources have ISO3 and ISO2 codes

Comment: You can't edit JSON using QGIS, only open & save to.

Comment: So is it perfectly possible or not at all?

Comment: It is perfectly possible. Load data, save json to shp/gpkg, join, edit, save to json.

Comment: Thanks Erik. I didn't know that conversion to Shapefile would be necessary. Thanks very much, it worked. If you'd like to add your comments into an answer, I will gladly accept it